# There's a way to vuetify snackbar opens just once?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm inserting a snackbar and would like to know if it has a way to make it appear only once for the user using browser's cache.

This is what i got so far.

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-snackbar
      v-model="snackbar"
      :bottom="y === 'bottom'"
      :left="x === 'left'"
      :multi-line="mode === 'multi-line'"
      :right="x === 'right'"
      :timeout="timeout"
      :top="y === 'top'"
      :vertical="mode === 'vertical'"
    >
      <router-link :to="rota" @click="snackbar = false" id="snackbarTexto"
        ><span>{{ text }}</span></router-link
      >
      <v-btn id="btnSnackbar" flat @click="snackbar = false">
        Fechar
      </v-btn>
    </v-snackbar>
  </v-card>
</template>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
   return {
      snackbar: true,
      y: "top",
      x: null,
      mode: "",
      timeout: 0,
      text: "Clique aqui para preencher a avaliação do módulo",
      rota: "/avaliacao_modulo"
    };
  }
})
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OGwzGG

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to use **LocalStorage** to save snackbar data on the client.

1.When the component is first created, get the value of **mySnackbarValue** stored in localStorage and set it to the value of **snackbar** of our component data if it exits in localStorage.

```
created(){
    if (localStorage.getItem('mySnackbarValue')) this.snackbar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mySnackbarValue'));
}
```

**NOTE:** Since **LocalStorage** stores strings only, so, `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mySnackbarValue'));` parses back to Boolean.

2.Now, we to need set the value of **mySnackbarValue** in our localStorage when the **snackbar** value of component data changes by using watch.

```
watch:{
    snackbar:{
        handler(){
            localStorage.setItem('mySnackbarValue', this.snackbar);
        },
    },
}
```

3.**snackbar** in data component is set true by default.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
   return {
      snackbar: true
    };
  }
})
```

The complete code is as follows:

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-snackbar
      v-model="snackbar"
      :bottom="y === 'bottom'"
      :left="x === 'left'"
      :multi-line="mode === 'multi-line'"
      :right="x === 'right'"
      :timeout="timeout"
      :top="y === 'top'"
      :vertical="mode === 'vertical'"
    >
      <router-link :to="rota" @click="snackbar = false" id="snackbarTexto"
        ><span>{{ text }}</span></router-link
      >
      <v-btn id="btnSnackbar" flat @click="snackbar = false">
        Fechar
      </v-btn>
    </v-snackbar>
  </v-card>
</template>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
   return {
      snackbar: true,
      y: "top",
      x: null,
      mode: "",
      timeout: 0,
      text: "Clique aqui para preencher a avaliação do módulo",
      rota: "/avaliacao_modulo"
    };
  },
  watch: {
    snackbar: {
      handler() {
        localStorage.setItem('mySnackbarValue', this.snackbar);
      },    
    },
  },
  created(){
   if (localStorage.getItem('mySnackbarValue')) this.snackbar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mySnackbarValue'));
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a library such as js-cookie to store a cookie denoting if the user has seen the snackbar message yet.

I'm not sure what type of build system you are using, or if you are using node/npm. You will have to import some type of cookie library, or manage the cookies yourself via vanilla JavaScript.

Also, I left the part of abstraction to you. Make sure that this is easy to change in case you want to implement any new types of messages later on. I hope this helps out!

```
<template>
    <v-card>
        <v-snackbar v-model="showSnackbar"
                    :bottom="y === 'bottom'"
                    :left="x === 'left'"
                    :multi-line="mode === 'multi-line'"
                    :right="x === 'right'"
                    :timeout="timeout"
                    :top="y === 'top'"
                    :vertical="mode === 'vertical'">
            <router-link :to="rota" @click="showSnackbar = false" id="snackbarTexto">
                <span>{{ text }}</span>
            </router-link>

            <v-btn id="btnSnackbar" flat @click="showSnackbar = false">
                Fechar
            </v-btn>
        </v-snackbar>
    </v-card>
</template>

// Import js-cookie
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie
import cookie from 'js-cookie';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
        return {
            // Set to false initially
            showSnackbar: false,

            y: "top",
            x: null,
            mode: "",
            timeout: 0,
            text: "Clique aqui para preencher a avaliação do módulo",
            rota: "/avaliacao_modulo"
        };
    },

    created() {
        // Give the snackbar cookie a name
        let cookieName = 'snackbar';

        // Check browser cookies for a snackbar cookie
        let snackbarCookie = cookie.get(cookieName);

        // If we have no cookie
        if (!snackbarCookie) {
            // Set a cookie so the snackbar doesn't come up again
            cookie.set(cookieName, true);

            // Show the snackbar
            this.showSnackbar = true;
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: thank you for repling, i will try that option and give you a feedback too!